# What is the encryption/ decryption algorithm used to interpret HL7 messages?

Tags: hl7

I wanted to know how the HL7 Messages are interpreted and what is the algorithm it uses to encrypt and decrypt the messages , based on the segments of the data passed.
Any leads on  this would be much appreciated

Comment: Messages themselves are not usually encrypted. They do have a very standard format though. This includes message type and version; segments; delimiters etc. This link may get you started feel free to ask follow up questions. http://www.hl7standards.com/blog/2006/10/05/what-are-the-components-of-an-hl7-message/

Comment: http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_section.cfm?section=1&ref=nav

Comment: Messages are in plain text, the most common version 2.x are pipe delimited. Encryption of the messages themselves are generally determined by the method of transportation.

Answer (score 2):

The HL7 standards don't define any encryption algorithm. Message transport is typically encrypted using TLS or some sort of VPN. For HL7 V2.X, the basic message interpretation rules are defined in chapter 2 of the standard.